# Gap between Extra Items in Bootstrap Thumbnail Grid

Tags: python, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

A list of N objects needs to be rendered as follows:

```
[Thumbnail 1] [Thumbnail 2] [Thumbnail 3] [Thumbnail 4]

[Thumbnail 5] [Thumbnail 6]
```

The number of objects, N, is dynamic. Assume N is 6 in above case for illustration purpose, **the gap between last two extra items (thumbnail 5, 6) is consistent with the gap in first row.**

However, my code always displays the last row like this

```
[Thumbnail 1] [Thumbnail 2] [Thumbnail 3] [Thumbnail 4]

[Thumbnail 5]               [Thumbnail 6]
```

Could you please point out how to correct this non-consistent gap in the last row?

In my Django template, here is the code

```
<div class='row row-flex movie-thumbnails clearfix'>

{% for movie in object_list %}
  <div class='col-md-3'>
  {% include "movie/movie_thumbnail.html" with movie=movie %}
  </div>
  {% cycle '' '' '' '</div><div class="row row-flex movie-thumbnails clearfix">' %}
{% endfor %}

</div>
```

The `.row-flex` class is to ensure all thumbnails having the same height.

Comment: Since it appears you're using flexbox, have you tried something along the lines of: `.thumbnail:last-child { margin-right: auto; }`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It does not affect the position. I am not using flexcontainer yet. but later I created a flexcontainer for all rows. It still does not have effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, the answer is very simple. Put the flex-grow as 0

```
.row-flex, .row-flex > div[class*='col-'] {  
    /*display: -moz-box;*/
    /*IE10 only supports the flexbox spec*/
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;
    /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
    display: flex;
    /* flex-shrink is 0 */
    flex:0 0 auto;
}
```